# access file using list inside list index python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using the below code to generate random combination of file

```
from itertools import product

comblist = []
 
comb = product([1, 2], repeat=8)
for i in comb:  # no list conversion needed
    a = i
    comblist.append(a)

print(comblist)
```

and the result is as below(only half shown):

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)]
```

i want each list inside list to be my file name for 8 files that i am opening
for eg there are 8 files i want to open

```
1 = open("1.txt", "r")
2 = open("1.txt", "r")
3 = open("1.txt", "r")
```

each file should be open using list inside list number using for loop.

can some python expert can help me with the code.
newbie here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly don't use numbers like 1,2,3 as variable names.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve?  e.g. what is the point of opening `1.txt` 8 times in a row?

Comment: sorry the file name is as follows w1.txt, x1.txt, y1.txt and so on.

Comment: you need to add more details to your question it is still confusing

Comment: How many files, do you want? Please explain in more details.

Comment: i am so sorry guys i am not good in english but trying to make you understand

Comment: so i have list of file names in list inside list as [[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)] and so on. all this are file name i have set. want to open 1st list inside list (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) as file open(a{1}.txt, open(b{1}.txt) and so on in loop so that every list set opens the files. hope that makes you understand

Answer (score 1):

This could be done like this:

```
#let the list name be var

for i in range(len(var)):
    for j in range(len(var[i])):
         temp = open("{0}.txt".format(var[i][j]))
         #perform any operations here because temp will be reset.
```

Comment: i want ot get it from the list inside list number as thats how i made it

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the error, now this should work. var is comblist in this case.